# How to generate 15 random characters for every user who signup

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im making login and registration sample page, after users signed up, they will go to the welcome page where their inputs in the registration was displayed, I have 3 fields that I already displayed (email, username and full name)  now I want also to display to their profile page the exact time they registered. Example: Registered date : 03 - 11 - 2018, and also I want to generate 12 random numbers and letters for every user who sign up as their registration ID and I also want to display on their profile page. These are my problem since last week, Ive been searching the internet but I cant find some tutorials, I hope you help me. Thanks. :) Every answer is appreciated.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `css`?

Comment: Plenty of scripts on the internet to generate GUIDS

Answer (score 0):

First you should add a `TIMESTAMP` column to your database and make its default to `CURRENT TIMESTAMP`. This will store the exact timestamp of data being inserted in the database, which is same to the time they have created their profile.

Then show the value of this column along with other columns(Name, Email, Username) to your welcome page and show it in a format `d-m-Y`

To generate a random number you can use PHP `rand()` function. Also combine php `time()` in it to get a unique random number. See the below code for reference.

```
  <?php $random = rand(10000, 99999); $rtime = time(); $user_id = $random."".$rtime; ?>
```

You can change the `rand()` variable to suit it to your requirements.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The common way of doing this is using [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function. It will not generate 12 random characters, but a more or less unique id (string of numbers and characters) for your user base. Might be just what you looking for.

Actually if you read through documentation, it's 13 characters by default

> With an empty prefix, the returned string will be 13 characters long.
>   If more_entropy is TRUE, it will be 23 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use uniqid() on registration, this will ensure that you have unique identifiers you can generate it as following

```
$user_identifier = uniqid();
```

As for their registration date, you should store it in your users table as datetime, then you extract it from database

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

### PHP Random String Function

This is a function for creating a random string with PHP.

```
function randomString($length) {                                
$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$string = '';    
for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) { $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters)-1)]; }
return $string;}
```

You can use the function like this.  for future reference you can change the 15 to whatever number you want to generate a string of that length.

```
$randString = randomString(15);
```

Note: you can add characters to the $characters string for expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code hope this will help you:

```
  <?php
function randomPassword() {
$alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789";
$pass = array(); //remember to declare $pass as an array
$alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; //put the length -1 in cache
for ($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) {
    $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
    $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];    } 
return implode($pass); //turn the array into a string }
  echo randomPassword(); ?>
```